# How to customize ion-range in disabled state?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

### Is there a way to customize the ion-range with the disabled property active?

Using `ion-range` as a visual cue to show where the user is in the (order)process. The user will not have the option to change the range, so the `disabled` property is added. This property overwrites all the custom color css. But I can't find the `disabled` css to overwrite it again to the desired result.

This is the custom css of the `ion-range`. The secondary color is the green color seen below.

[image]

Can we achieve the desired result below with the `ion-range` where the user can't control the slider?

```
<ion-range value="{{ range }}" min="0" max="2" color="secondary" disabled></ion-range>
```

**Result** (with disabled property)

[image: Result]

**Desired result** (without disabled property)

*[image: Desired result]*

### EDIT

Since you can't change the disabled property and it's css variables, we want to display the slider without pointer or touch control by the user.

Comment: What specifically do you want to change? you've already set it up to equal the value of 'range' which works whether or not its disabled.

Comment: @IraW Thanks for the reply. I updated the question. In short we want to use the range slider for a visual cue. So the user will not have the ability to change or control the slider. Therefor we added the disabled property, but now we lose and can't change/overwrite the colors and other css variables...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pointer-events:none` stops you from interacting with it

```
<ion-range style="pointer-events: none;"value="{{ range }}" min="0" max="2" color="secondary"></ion-range>
```

:) my final answer

Comment: Perfect, I had the same idea from your previous answer ;)

Comment: Doesn't work with Ionic 6  :-(

Answer (score 1):

just add style="pointer-events: none;"